# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.AsyncSupportConfigurer

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

trying to convert and old app into a spring boot app and getting the above error. I've been seeing a lot of threads regarding missing dependencies but I'm not sure which one I'm missing, if I am indeed missing one to begin with? No libraries are missing from any other portion of code but I'm clearly missing something? Or on second thought it is could it be I'm import unnecessary dependencies that are cluttering up the app making it not start as well?

See below for a redacted snippet of the gradle.build containing dependencies and also a redacted list of the stack trace.

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version:'1.4.1'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version:'2.3'
    compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version:'20041127.091804'
    compile group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version:'1.7.2'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version:'2.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version:'3.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version:'4.3.5'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version:'20140107'
    compile group: 'com.itextpdf.tool', name: 'xmlworker', version:'5.5.6'
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version:'1.2.17'
    compile group: 'org.quartz-scheduler', name: 'quartz', version:'2.2.1'
    compile group: 'org.quartz-scheduler', name: 'quartz-jobs', version:'2.2.1'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support', version:'3.1.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version:'3.1.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-tx', version:'3.1.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version:'4.0.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'c3p0', name: 'c3p0', version:'0.9.1.2'
    compile group: 'mssqlserver', name: 'sqljdbc4', version:'3.0'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin', version: '2.1.6.RELEASE', ext: 'pom'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: '2.5.1'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: '4.3.18.RELEASE'

}
```

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$EndpointWebMvcConfiguration due to org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/AsyncSupportConfigurer not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:55) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:444) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    etc...
    at com.dish.wfm.controller.SamsungUpdateJobApplication.main(SamsungUpdateJobApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/AsyncSupportConfigurer
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    etc...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.AsyncSupportConfigurer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    ... 36 common frames omitted

org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration] for bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration overrides final method configureHandlerExceptionResolvers.(Ljava/util/List;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1394) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:641) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE] 
    etc...
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration overrides final method configureHandlerExceptionResolvers.(Ljava/util/List;)V
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    etc...
```

Comment: You are mixing jars from different spring versions. Remove **all** the `org.springframework` dependencies. Those are all already in the `spring-boot-starter` dependencies. Also remove the `javax.mail` dependency and add `spring-boot-starter-mail` as a dependency. I also hardly believe you will need the plugin as a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependencies are a bit of a mess. You have dependencies that are already managed by the `spring-boot-starter-*` dependencies. However you are overriding those with manual `org.springframework` dependencies from different Spring versions. You are mixing 2.5.1, 3.1.0, 3.1.3, 4.0.6 and 4.1.3. Mixing jars from different versions of any framework is a bad idea they are generally incompatible.

To fix, remove the `org.springframework` dependencies, those interfere/break the Spring Boot managed dependencies.

Next you don't need the `spring-boot-gradle-plugin` as a dependency and finally the `javax.mail` stuff is part of the `spring-boot-starter-mail`. A

This would result in the following list of dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version:'2.3'
    compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version:'20041127.091804'
    compile group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version:'1.7.2'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version:'2.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version:'3.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version:'4.3.5'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version:'20140107'
    compile group: 'com.itextpdf.tool', name: 'xmlworker', version:'5.5.6'
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version:'1.2.17'
    compile group: 'org.quartz-scheduler', name: 'quartz', version:'2.2.1'
    compile group: 'org.quartz-scheduler', name: 'quartz-jobs', version:'2.2.1'
    compile group: 'c3p0', name: 'c3p0', version:'0.9.1.2'
    compile group: 'mssqlserver', name: 'sqljdbc4', version:'3.0'

    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'

}
```

### NOTES

Depending on the Spring Boot version you are using you could also use `spring-boot-starter-quartz` for quartz (or remove the `version` element from the dependencies).

Spring Boot 2.x doesn't support log4j 1 so you might want to replace that with logback (the default) or log4j2 (using the `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` dependency).

I would also suggest replacing C3P0 with the default HikariCP (saves you a dependency and is imho a better connection pool).

You could also remove the `version` from the GSON dependency as Spring Boot also manages that (and that way you have a compatible version).

Answer (score 0):

remove dependency `spring-webmvc`. Because `AsyncSupportConfigurer` is a class that exists since 3.2.

In fact, you can remove the `org.springframework` related dependencies. And it is safe.